# C# to Python converter

Tags: c#, python

I have a large C# library that I need to convert to Python. Python is a customer requirement, I can not use any other language.

Any automatic C# to Python converter?

Edit: I need a pure Python solution. .Net is not an option for me.

Comment: Hmm, very tricky. Can they be talked into using IronPython?

Comment: Use IronPython, find a Python equivalent library, or rewrite the library by hand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming IronPython will meet their requirement, SharpDevelop can do that for you.  I have a feeling it will still be quite painful.

Here's a link:

http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/mattward/archive/2009/05/11/ConvertingCSharpVBNetCodeToIronPython.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You should convince your costumer that Python language can interact with .Net using some libraries. It would be a waste of time to re write the whole library in Python and then test the Python code for any bugs.

There is a library called [Python for .NET](http://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/readme.html#getting_started), by which you can call .net classes and functions inside your Python code, you can create a wrapper code for calling the .Net code.

If you write a wrapper class, it would be just like calling Python classes and functions to other Python programmers.

Comment: Hey, Searock, how would you suggest running that .Net on iOS and Android? Will probably point me to Xamarin, Mono, etc? I just need the C# to Python converter.

Comment: @user695797 Sorry didn't know you wanted to run the code on iOS and Android.

Comment: @user695797 In that case you could use a code convertor but it won't translate the complete code for you, you still need to write some code by yourself.